# findLastIndex is not a function，how，why

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const list = [1,2,100,50,100,20]
const index = list.findLastIndex((item)=>item===100)
console.log(index)
// TypeError: list.findLastIndex is not a function
```

**Can we say that this method does not exist, but it does exist in MDN**

Comment: Well which node-version are you using?

Comment: Hmm.. it's compatible with most browsers and Node.js versions. What Node version are you on?

Comment: `arr` is NOT `list` variable.

Comment: You can use lastIndexOf method instead of findLastIndex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look at [compatibility info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex#browser_compatibility)

it is not supported below node 18.

check your node version

```
    node -v
```

Or

```
    node --version
```

Comment: Thanks，I need to upgrade my node version to 18